# ngx-perfect-scrollbar: How to reference to the directive from typescript?

Tags: angular, scroll, perfect-scrollbar

I'm using `ngx-perfect-scrollbar` with my Angular 5 project. I want to scroll the `div` to top when the route changes.

**dashboard.html**

```
<div class="main-panel" [perfectScrollbar] #perfectscroll>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**dashboard.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-dashboard',
    templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('perfectscroll') perfectscroll: PerfectScrollbarDirective;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
            if (!(evt instanceof NavigationEnd)) {
                return;
            }
            this.perfectscroll.scrollToTop()
        });
    }
}
```

But I get this error :

> TypeError: _this.perfectscroll.scrollToTop is not a function

Comment: does this problem solved?  Kindly post or accept the solution.

Answer (score 6):

Look at my working example.

In the trmplate:

```
<div class="perfectScroll" [perfectScrollbar] #psLeft="ngxPerfectScrollbar">...</div>
...
<div class="perfectScroll" [perfectScrollbar] #psRight="ngxPerfectScrollbar">...</div>
```

...

In the component:

```
@ViewChild('psLeft') psLeft: PerfectScrollbarDirective;
@ViewChild('psRight') psRight: PerfectScrollbarDirective;
...
if (this.psRight) {
    this.psRight.scrollToTop();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

just use this:
@ViewChild(PerfectScrollbarDirective) perfectscroll: PerfectScrollbarDirective;

you will have instance and then you can call functions like scrollToTop()

Comment: But what if I have multiple scrollbars on the page?

Answer (score 0):

All of these solutions didn't work for me. I've fixed like below

```
scrollUp(): void {
  const container = document.querySelector('.main-panel');
  container.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me

```
  @ViewChild(PerfectScrollbarDirective, { static: false }) perfectScrollbarDirectiveRef?: PerfectScrollbarDirective;
```